# What is /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:01\:00.0/?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, fan, devices

Recently I had a problem with the fan working all the time.

Someone suggested to use `powertop --auto-tune` or to write `auto` into `/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:01\:00.0/power/control`

My question is:

What is `/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:01\:00.0` ? - I guess it points to some device (probably my NVIDIA graphic controller). How do I know which device is which? What is meant by `0000` and `:01` and `:00.0`? - Where can I find an explanation for how the devices are written?

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Answer (score 2):

`/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/control`

- [sys](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sysfs.5.html) is a virtual filesytem that allows you to get information about the system and its components in a structured way.
- /sys/bus/ This directory contains one subdirectory for each of the
  bus types in the kernel.  Inside each of these directories
  are two subdirectories:

  ```
         devices
                This subdirectory contains symbolic links to
                entries in /sys/devices that correspond to the
                devices discovered on this bus.

         drivers
                This subdirectory contains one subdirectory for
                each device driver that is loaded on this bus.
  ```

The `0000:01:00.0`:

- "0000" is the PCI domain
- "01" points to the PCI bus number in that domain
- "00" is the device number
- "0" is the function in the device

Often you see it described like this: `/sys/bus/pci/devices/<Domain>:<Bus>:<Device>.<Function>/power/control`

- power/controle is used to manipulate runtime power management.

[nvidia has a large manual on this](https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/435.17/README/dynamicpowermanagement.html#Introduction70e5e). [Chapter 22](https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/435.17/README/dynamicpowermanagement.html) is about this function.